# How to Limit Login Attempts with LDAP

Tags: java, ldap

I am working on limiting the login attempts of users in my web application.

I would like the users to wait for X min after Y unsuccessful attempts.

We are using LDAP so i wonder if there is a way to do that with native LDAP functionality or do i need to develop this feature on my own.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "standard" for performing this using LDAP.

Most LDAP server implementation have a server-side method to enforce these constraints on any user bind.

You could ask the LDAP administrator to implement the requirement.

Otherwise, you will need to implement the constraint within the Application.
-jim

Answer (score 0):

If you're using OpenLDAP you can do this with the password policy overlay.